# insert Using ajax But page refreshing on submit why?

Tags: codeigniter

```
    Controller code I have :

<?php
class Ajax_cntrl extends CI_controller{


    public function index(){

        $this->load->view('ajax_view');
         $insert = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),//<-- also not able to get this id from ajax post request
        'pass' => $this->input->post('pass'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        );
        $this->db->insert('form',$insert);//<--insert item into cart
        $query;// to insert into database

        //redirect('shop');

    }
}


?>
```

view code I have ::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pass</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){


            var form_data = {            //repair
            id: id,
            name: $('#name_' + id).val(),
            pass: $('#pass' + id).val(),
            email: $('#email' + id).val(),
            mobile: $('#email' + id).val(),
            address: $('#email' + id).val()
        };

$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:"<?php echo site_url('ajax_cntrl/index'); ?>",
    data: form_data, // $(this).serialize(); you can use this too
        success: function(msg) {
              alert("success..!! ");
        }
        });
            return false;
    });


</script>
```

problem is that when i am submitting the form it refreshing the browser ajax not working where is the fault m not able to understand please help me related in this why ajax call is not working there and is that a gud way to implement ajax with codeigniter ?? if yes then y its not working

Comment: can u please update my code as what you said with that

Comment: I think you just need ```e.preventDefault()```

Comment: not working ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code, this will fix your issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form_data = {//repair
                name: $('#name').val(),
                pass: $('#pass').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                mobile: $('#mobile').val(),
                address: $('#address').val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "<?php echo site_url('ajax_cntrl/index'); ?>",
                data: form_data,
                dataType: 'json', 
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert("success..!! ");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: page is not refreshing but the data not inserting in to the database ... not working

Comment: Yes of course because how will you get value of `id` in ajax call  `var form_data = { id: id,` here?

Comment: not understand .. can u please update the code ..it inserting all fields value 0 in the database and after inserting fields have remain old values

Comment: @Gaurav : Glad to help you friend.

Comment: can u please expalin me what was the error and why we use e.preventDefault();

Comment: Of course, Please refer this link. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: In sort it will disable `default action` and perform `user defined action`.

Comment: after ajax call field have the values in their input boxes how can it auto remove after ajax call

Comment: add this line in your ajax success function `$("form").trigger('reset');`